# What is the correct way to use "neither" and "nor" in a sentence together?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, negation, disjunction

Given these facts:

1. The tool cannot be found in the kitchen.
2. The tool cannot be found in the bathroom.

Which is the correct sentence to represent the situation above?

> 1. I *can* find the tool neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.
> 2. I *cannot* find the tool neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.
> 3. I *cannot* find the tool, neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.

Comment: *I can find the tool neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom* or *I cannot find the tool in either the kitchen or the bathroom*

Comment: Normal people in normal speech don't use 'nor'. The preferred way to say this is either the second of snumpy's examples or: "I can't find it. It's not in the kitchen or the bathroom."

Comment: Educated people in normal speech use "nor" all the time.

Comment: Another variation, that sounds good to me, is "I **cannot** find the tool in the kitchen **nor** in the bathroom." Not submitting it as an answer since I'm not sure.

Comment: I am a person of questionable education and stature, yet I use 'nor' all the time.

Comment: Neither MikTeX nor TeXLive seem to have a converter from PDF to EPS. Does such a tool actually exist in either package, and if not, where would I find one?

Comment: @Henrik N that is how I would phrase that sentence, I would say that is Standard American, might not be textbook English.

Comment: I can't find the tool in the kitchen nor bathroom.

Comment: As a native English speaker, both `I cannot find the tool, neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom` and `I cannot find the tool, either in the kitchen or in the bathroom` sound fine and mean the same thing to me (though the former sounds a little more formal). Not sure if a prescriptivist would differ, though.

Comment: Needs the comma!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The *neither/nor* combination expresses negation all by itself. Therefore it should be used with a positive statement. The following is correct.

> I can find the tool neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.

Comment: Is it just me or is it also true for a native speaker that the following example: "It is neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom." sounds much more natural than "I can find ... neither ... nor"?

Comment: @Unreason: I think that sounds more natural because it's a simpler sentence. But "I can find ... neither ... nor" is unexceptionable.

Comment: I certainly agree with *...it should be used with a positive...* I'm not 100% sure, but I think the corollary *'neither' should not be used with a negative* is also true. But the great lexical unwashed can't never get enough negation, so doubtless they do it all the time.

Comment: To me, this sentence sounds strange, but changing the word order makes it sound normal.  I would say "I can neither find the tool in the kitchen nor in the bathroom."  I'm not sure if other people would agree.

Comment: @neil: You have *neither* governing the verb; this is a misusage. You either have to nave nor govern another verb or else switch it back to the noun, the way I had it. *Neither* is a conjunction that works with the correlative conjunction nor to address two like objects or actions.

Answer (score 20):

Or for simplicity you could just leave out the neither/either

> I can't find the tool in the kitchen
>   or the bathroom

is perfectly understandable.

This also has the advantage of working when talking to computer programmers who would look confused if you had searched for a single tool in the kitchen AND the bathroom.

Comment: +1 because even though technically speaking both @Robusto and @Martha are right on the grammaticality issue, you're far more right in terms of what it would be more desirable to actually say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ultimately the point of language is to get the idea across - unless you're a lawyer or a philosophy major.

Comment: You're getting me worried now. I was all fired up for philosophy.se beta - but I shan't like it if verbosity rules there! :)

Comment: It feels like a case of emphasis. This form tends to emphasize that you can't find the tool, whereas the neither/nor form tends to emphasize where you can't find it.

Answer (score 17):

You need to *either* use a negative verb ("cannot"), *or* use *neither/nor*. Using the two together, like what that editor did to your post in TeX, is incorrect.

> I can find the tool neither in the kitchen nor the bathroom.

> I can't find the tool either in the kitchen or the bathroom.

> <del>I can't find the tool neither in the kitchen nor the bathroom.</del>

I do want to note that, unless the context leads the reader to expect a negative, the "can find ... neither" version can be confusing. Thus, "can't find ... either" is in most cases the better choice.

Answer (score 9):

I know this has been answered, but I couldn't resist chiming in anyway.

Think of it this way:

- Neither = not either
- Nor = Not or

> I cannot find the tool not either in the kitchen not or in the bathroom.

Cannot + not = Can => I can => not what you're trying to express

Comment: @Kitḫ not a mnemonic -- that is the etymology, I believe.

Comment: @Kris Whether or not it is the etymology, it can still be a mnemonic.

Answer (score 3):

> I can find the tool in neither the kitchen nor the bathroom.

I don't think you need two `in`s. And as has been suggested you don't need a not if you're using a neither.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it is to consider the sentence:

> I have neither the time, nor the patience to deal with you today.

It wouldn't make any sense at all if the word *haven't* was inserted in place of *have*.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, only the the first sentence is unambiguously correct:

> I can find the tool neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.

But what's intriguing to me is the third sentence in which a comma has been introduced. Without that comma, the sentence is unequivocally wrong. But a comma can be used to separate two independent clauses. Combine that with the concept of elision, and the third sentence could actually be interpreted as:

> I cannot find the tool, it is neither in the kitchen nor in the bathroom.

I dislike that punctuation and I would either use a semicolon or make it two sentences. But if the sentence is interpreted that way then it only has a minor punctuation issue, while the use of 'neither' and 'nor' is actually correct.