# "can't see neither A nor B" or "can see neither A nor B"

Tags: grammaticality, negation, neither-nor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Still confused with “neither…nor…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30075/still-confused-with-neither-nor)

> ...can't see neither A nor B.

Is that grammatically correct?

Or is this?

> ...can see neither A nor B.

What if "can't" was used?

Answer (score 4):

"Can't see neither" is a double negative:

> Can not see neither A nor B

The second example is more correct:

> I can see neither A nor B

You can also say:

> I cannot see A or B

Answer (score 3):

You can't use two negatives in single English sentence.

> I can see neither, A nor B

is correct

Comment: By the way, you don't need the comma.