# Using "neither" without "nor"

Tags: neither-nor

I'm trying to improve on the last part of this sentence:

> Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, **although he did not provide the names of its authors, either.**

My first instinct is:

> Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, **although he neither provided the names of its authors**.

But something feels wrong here, and I can't explain why.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, though he did not provide the names of its authors.`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use "neither" and "nor" in a sentence together?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30075/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-neither-and-nor-in-a-sentence-together)

Comment: Leave out *neither* or *though*; use *but* or *and* or semicolon:   “Mirabeau noted the text was not his, but did not give the names of its authors” or “Mirabeau said the text was not his, and didn't give its authors' names”.

Comment: The suggested duplicate only addresses 'neither' when used with 'nor'.

Answer (score 4):

Using 'neither' after a non-negative-verb main clause (Mirabeau pointed out ...) does not work.

> *John said he didn't like tomatoes, though he neither went to buy any.

A valid sentence is:

> John didn't say he liked tomatoes, and neither did he buy any.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to introduce a preposition or conjunction or two to make it work. 'Although' seems to me to be the word that is cramping things, as it does some of the work of 'neither' too.

Possibilities:

Whilst Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, neither did he provide the names of its authors.

Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, but neither did he provide the names of its authors.

Edit 6/July/2020.
It was six years ago that I wrote this. And just thinking of it again, I am wondering why "neither" is used at all. The first clause is not strictly negative (*He pointed out*...). So *neither* seems out of place.

I think it is better written:
*Mirabeau pointed out that the text was not his, although he did not provide the names of its authors*.

Comment: Why is "but" needed in your second alternative? It sounds a lot more natural without it.

Comment: I think part of what feels wrong about it, to me, is that "neither" doesn't follow a negative verb. Isn't that the general rule?

"Mirabeau never denied that the text was not his, but neither did he provide the names of its authors." 

... That changes the meaning a bit of "pointed out", but it provides an example.

Comment: You have the correct answer, @Matt. From Google dictionary [bolding mine]: used to introduce a further **negative** statement.
"he didn't remember, and neither did I". Post this as an answer.

Comment: @Irene On reflection I think 'and' would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

"although he did not provide the names of its authors, either(*)" is correct because the use of "neither" in the middle of the sentence is not connected to the logical expression to justify an exclusion.

(*) But to make it better we'd rather strike the fnal word "either" which is useless and heavy.
Then we'd have : "Mirabeau pointed out (that) the text was not his, although he did not provide the names of its authors". We do not need here this "either".